# how to use variable in user control from form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list in a form and I want to access this list from `Form1` in user control.

The following code line would be in `Form1`:

```
public partial class form : Form
{
    public static List<daftarBarang> tambahBarang = new List<daftarBarang>();
}

//UserControl
parent.tambahBarang.Add(new daftarBarang(nama, harga, stok, parent.tambahBarang.Count));
```

The issue is I cannot use my list, if I don't use static then the list won't save the results.

Comment: WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Pass a reference of the list into your UserControl.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want it to be static or not? If it's static, then you use `form.tambahBarang.Add`, not `parent.tambahBarang.Add`.

Comment: `tambahBarang` should probably not be `static`. Show us where `parent` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly how you wired up your `Form` and `UserControl` but here's an example of a `UserControl` that works as a container which displays the items that you add via `AddItem`.

If this example does not help you to solve your problem please provide us with more information so that we can assist you further.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public class DaftarBarang
    {
        public string Nama { get; set; }
        public int Harga { get; set; }
    }

    public class TheUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private readonly BindingList<DaftarBarang> list = new BindingList<DaftarBarang>();

        public TheUserControl()
        {
            var grid = new DataGridView
            {
                DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null)
            };

            AutoSize = true;
            Controls.Add(grid);
        }

        public void AddItem(DaftarBarang barang)
        {
            list.Add(barang);
        }
    }

    public class TheForm : Form
    {       
        public TheForm()
        {
            var uc = new TheUserControl();
            uc.AddItem(new DaftarBarang { Nama = "Sepatu olahraga", Harga = 255000 });
            uc.AddItem(new DaftarBarang { Nama = "Baju cantik", Harga = 85000 });

            Controls.Add(uc);
         }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new TheForm());
        }
    }
}
```